# Get output location for a SourceFile given CompilerOptions

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Is it possible to get the output location for a `SourceFile` given a set of `CompilerOptions` when using the compiler API?

I could mimic the way TypeScript resolves this path using `outDir`, `rootDir` and the set of included filepaths, but this really doesn't seem like a good idea (for obvious reasons).

I noticed the `ts.getOutputFileNames` and `ts.getTsBuildInfoEmitOutputFilePath` functions, which look promising, but the first one takes a `ts.ParsedCommandLine` (which doesn't make sense with programmatic use) and the second one seems to return `undefined` regardless of the `CompilerOptions` I put in.

**Edit:**

I examined the compiler's code, and it looks like [it's using `getOwnEmitOutputFilePath`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f31b5a278f03b2e2d2713ed64230f853ae6b4545/src/compiler/emitter.ts#L93) to calculate this path during 'regular compilation'. Unfortunately, [this function](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f31b5a278f03b2e2d2713ed64230f853ae6b4545/src/compiler/utilities.ts#L3794-L3805) is marked as internal, which means it's not *easily* accessible for API usage.

Even if this function is accessed (for example by manually augmenting it's type), it requires an [`EmitHost`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f31b5a278f03b2e2d2713ed64230f853ae6b4545/src/compiler/types.ts#L5965-L5984) which is sadly also marked as internal.
Strangely enough the `TransformationContext` interface does have an (internal) [`getEmitHost`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f31b5a278f03b2e2d2713ed64230f853ae6b4545/src/compiler/types.ts#L5998) function, but this has always returned `undefined` during my testing, probably because I'm using the programmatic `transform` function rather than a full-blown compilation.

In other words: I'd have to manually construct an `EmitHost`.
It looks like this is done in two places in the compiler, [inside `createProgram`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f31b5a278f03b2e2d2713ed64230f853ae6b4545/src/compiler/program.ts#L1469-L1503) and [in the emitter itself](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f31b5a278f03b2e2d2713ed64230f853ae6b4545/src/compiler/emitter.ts#L749-L802). Sadly, in both cases this 'constructor' is inaccessible for programmatic use.
Manually implementing an `EmitHost` doesn't seem like a viable solution either due to the usage of internal API's.

I feel like I'm out of options at this point. Is there any other (public) way to access this information, or should this be considered a feature request?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the same hunt today. I came across your other question as well.

What you're looking for is `ts.getOutputFileNames()`. At first, I was worried it might not match what emit gives, however, a friend pointed out that it was [created for ts-loader](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33503/), so it should be just fine!

In order to use it, you can generate a quick `ParsedCommandLine` based on your options and files.

If you have a full tsconfig file, you can just use `ts.getParsedCommandLineOfConfigFile()`. (For host, just supply `ts.sys as any`)

Or if you'd like to synthesize one, you can use `ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent()`:

```
  const cfg = {
    files: [ '/path/to/FileA', '/path/to/FileB' ], // your filepaths here
    compilerOptions: {} // your compilerOptions here
  }
  parsedCommandLine = ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent(cfg, /* host */ ts.sys as any, /* baseDir */ process.cwd())!;
```

I assume you'll have your own values for baseDir, files, and compilerOptions.

**Note**: Don't worry about creating a new parsedCommandLine. Testing shows it takes 2ms, so it's not costly.

Hope it helps!