# Access ParsedCommandLine from transformer API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Is it possible to access the `ParsedCommandLine` from a custom transformer?

As I currently understand it, `ParsedCommandLine` and `CompilerOptions` are the equivalent of `tsconfig.json` and the `compilerOptions` section of it (respectively).
The `CompilerOptions` are accessible from the `TransformationContext`, but this information is not enough to do things like [resolving output locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097931/get-output-location-for-a-sourcefile-given-compileroptions) using `ts.getOutputFileNames`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does not pass that along. However, it does add `configFilePath` to `CompilerOptions` (at least that which is returned by `program.getCompilerOptions()`, I assume the one provided by `TransformationContext` would have it as well)

You cant use that with `ts.getParsedCommandLineOfConfigFile(configFilePath, undefined, (<any>ts.sys))`